# Validate the array inputs value to already selected or not

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-validation

I want to validate the array inputs value to already selected or not. In my case, I am using Laravel Livewire and I have dynamic inputs such as I can add new options like Size, Color. But I do not want to select the same value in two inputs like the select size in two inputs. Basically, If select the same value in the second input, I want to show it already selected.

[image]

Below code livewire controller,

```php
public $i = -1;
public $inputs = [];
public $options = ['Size', 'Color', 'Material', 'Style'];
public $option_name; 

function rules()
{
    $rules = [];

    if ($this->inputs) {
        foreach ($this->inputs as $key => $val) {
            $rules['option_name.' . $val] =  ['required'];
        }
        return $rules;
    }
}

public function addLine($i)
{  
    $i = $i + 1;
    $this->i = $i;
    array_push($this->inputs, $i);
}

public function updated($propertyName)
{ 
    if ($this->inputs) {
        $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
    }
}
```

Below code livewire view code,

```html
@forelse ($inputs as $key => $value)
    <x-native-select label="Option name" :options="$options" wire:model="option_name.{{ $value }}"/> // I am using livewire-wireui 
@empty
@endforelse
    
<a wire:click="addLine({{ $i }})" class="mt-4 text-sm cursor-pointer">
    + Add another option
</a>
```

Any idea how to validate this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me see how it goes.

```
public function updatedOptionName($selectedOption) {
//You can use laravel collection filter as well depending on how commplicated you want it
  $this->options = array_filter($this->options, function ($value) {
    return $value != $selectedOption;
  }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
}
```

The above function would filter out the selected option so that the option is not available when it is already selected. It might be overkill and subject to improvement from the community. All reviews are welcome. One thing to note is that you might want a sort of reset method in case the user decides to start all over again. Something along the lines of `public $originalOptions` that you would want to set on mount and then a reset function that assigns `this->options` to it. Let me know if it works.

More info on those functions [Lifecycle hooks](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: Hello, @Mrtorks . The above code didn't work for me. previously I did the below code but it effects the already selected option also, 'public $options = ['Size', 'Color', 'Material', 'Style'];
    public $OptionsListTwo = ['Size', 'Color', 'Material', 'Style']; public function updated($propertyName)
    { 
        if ($this->inputs) {
            $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
            $this->options = array_diff($this->OptionsListTwo, $this->option_name);
        }
    }'

Comment: @MadushanSerasinghe I have updated my answer. try and lets see.

Comment: now working but the same as array_diff which I told you. it also effects already selected input. I mean when if I select size from input one, size is not available in the second input list as I expect but the problem is size also disappears from the first input also because now $this->option has no size. Do you have any idea how to solve that case?

Comment: please see the image https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNWSgwb1cF5eePqZevU9iA27aYiRo4eTOj0u65e_QQ9uvVLZq3wSF5ZR577o3p9Fw/photo/AF1QipMiKEjUz9RqPYhrhBVLW__Ddv4VWWUonvcRjhqQ?key=SDAwZ29WOHR2RzFWTUdGSmhpemJpV1JxREpOak5B

Comment: @MadushanSerasinghe From what you are describing you cant bind one `wire:model` in multiple places and have them act independently. Your best bet is to write a custom function to check when option_name is updated against an array of selected options that you build in sync. You can then throw an error saying that the option is already selected.

Comment: You can also go the old javascript route to avoid any hassle and prop disabled on the option @MadushanSerasinghe. In my opinion that is the best way to do it. I would update my answer with a sample.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251848/discussion-between-mrtorks-and-madushan-serasinghe).

Comment: Do you have any idea if can use rules to show error messages such as the already selected, like Laravel unique rule?

Comment: You can change you rules property to return a rules array with a custom implementation. It tends to be a headache and a mess sometimes.